# ¿Cómo diferenciar el archivo en español de Stanford Core NLP Models?

Tags: android-studio

Estoy utilizando Android Estudio. Tengo el archivo jar de Stanford Core NLP Models 4.2.0, pero quiero reducir enormemente el espacio del archivo jar, por lo que quiero eliminar todos los demás archivos redundantes:

[image: ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la carga actual del modelo y todo funciona perfectamente, pero como he dicho, es tremendamente pesado y lento:
[image: ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intenté agregar en la carpeta libs solo el modelo en español que quiero y también nombrar todas las rutas que lo involucran, pero el resultado ha sido nullPointerExceptions ya que, según Android Studio, el archivo no existe:

Estaré encantado si alguien pudiera ayudarme. ¡Gracias de antemano!
[image: ingrese la descripción de la imagen aquí]